# How to Remove highlight style from button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is it possibile to remove a highlight style from a button in code behind in c#?

This is my Button declaration:

```
 var button = new Button() { Content = text };
 button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
 button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
 TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(button, true);
 button.style = ????
```

Comment: what kind of highlight style? Are you talking about the effect that occurs when the button is clicked?

Comment: i would remove Pressed Visual Style from a Button in a code

Comment: yes ..remove it by override the control template of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every button has a template attached to it and in ever template there are multiple visual states like pressed disabled etc.

You need to play with the visual states of a button and you could do it with the help of a style

Just look at the style below.

```
<Style x:Key="style_ColorButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Using this style with a button.

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" BorderThickness="0" Name="btnAcceptCrop" Click="btnAcceptCrop_Click" Style="{StaticResource style_ColorButton}" Background="Black" ForeGround="White"/>
```

setting the style in code

```
btnAcceptCrop.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["style_ColorButton"];
```

Declaring a style in a Page

Below all the namespace declaration in your page

Just make a tag

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and declare your style inside it.

Hope this helps.